# In a random sample of $6$ candies, what is the probability that at least one color is not included?

Tags: probability

According to the Mars Candy Company, the longrun
percentages of various colors of M&M milk
chocolate candies are as follows:
Blue: $24\%$
Orange: $20\%$
Green: $16\%$
Yellow: $14\%$
Red: $13\%$
Brown: $13\%$

In a random sample of $6$ candies, what is the probability that at least one color is not included?

The answer is $0.077$, but I'm not sure how to get to it.

Since the question says "at least one color is not included" I think its more simple to do $1 - P(\text{every colour is included})$. $n = 6$. 
I set the equation as want $1$ of each candy $$1 - \frac{6!}{1!^6}(0.24)^1 (0.2)^1 (0.16)^1 (0.14)^1 (0.13)^1 (0.13)^1$$ 
However, I believe I am approaching this wrong

Comment: Since the question says "at least one color is not included" I think its more simple to do 1 - P(every colour is included) 

n = 6 I set the equation as want 1 of each candy

1  -  (6! / (1!)^6)  (0.24)^1 (0.2)^1 (0.16)^1 (0.14)^1 (0.13)^1 (0.13)^1

However I believe I am approaching this wrong

Comment: Good stuff. If you put that in the body of your question, it will help attract others to assist you.

Comment: You say the answer is $0.077$, but I don't think that looks correct. That is saying you have a $92.3%$ chance of selecting one of each candies at random from a sample space which is quite even. I think the answer you're checking against is incorrect.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  The answer key is wrong.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.